# What's the best way to write unit tests for a REST API?

Tags: api, unit-testing, http, rest, testing

When writing unit tests for an API wrapper, should I be making real calls to the REST API endpoints or should I use mocl responses that simulate successful and erroneous calls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Unit tests** mean testing only your *unit* (API wrapper), nothing else. Thus, unfortunately, you should mock the entire API.

On the other hand this never really gives me enough confidence, so I go for **system tests** (also known as component tests). In that case you should run your API wrapper against existing API, maybe embedded and started along with your test. In **integration test**, the ultimate scenario, you run your API wrapper against real, but most likely test instance of the API (sandbox, dev environment).

In well established area of database testing: unit tests mock entire DAO level, component tests run against in-memory database while integration tests connect to real database with some fake data.